# Alternando resultados de ngRepeat en AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Tengo un blog cuyo contenido se completa a través de un controlador de AngularJS que trae los datos desde una base.

Por otro lado, tengo un objeto que contiene un listado de anuncios publicitarios que se muestran en formato de imagen.

El inconveniente está cuando pretendo mostrar 2 anuncios cada 4 posts. No sé cómo hacer para que se muestren todos los anuncios. Tal como está ahora siempre se muestran los 2 primeros. Creo que la clave está en "limitTo" pero o logro hacer que el bucle inicie desde el último anuncio mostrado.

El código que actualmente estoy usando es algo así:

```
<div ng-controller="noticias">
  <div ng-repeat-start="noticia in noticias">
    <h1>{{ noticia.titulo }}</h1>
    <p>{{ noticia.asunto }}</p>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat-end ng-if="($index+1) % 4 ===0">
    <div ng-repeat="anuncio in anuncios | limitTo: 2>
      <img ng-src="anuncios/{{ anuncio.nombre }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LimitTo soporta un segundo parámetro que es Start, indica a que posición del array se aplica el limit.

En tu caso particular, podrías usar algo así:

```
<div ng-repeat="anuncio in anuncios | limitTo: 2:($index+1)/2-2">
```

En este plunkr, lo podés ver funcionando:

https://plnkr.co/edit/hkYq5LFobJadyuS9rJaI?p=preview

Espero que esto sea lo que estás buscando.

Answer (score 2):

Excelente la solución de KN_, para mejor entendimiento la expresión podría mejorarse así

```
<div ng-repeat="anuncio in anuncios | limitTo: 2:(($index+1)/2)-2">
```

Así se entiende mejor el parentizado y se sabe que operación se esta realizando, es bien que sabemos cual es el orden de prioridad que se ejecutan las operación en JS, pero no esta demás colocar los paracentesis para mayor legibilidad y entendimiento del código,

Saludos, gran aporte.